# How convert characters (Ã© to é)

Tags: csv, character-encoding

I want create a custom language pack for my website

So I have create a CSV file with the translation that goes to English to French

But in French language, there are this caractere é, è, à ...

So How I can convert this caractere to Ã©, Ã­ .. ?
(I do not even know the encoding)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific programming language in mind? Python seems like it would do well.

Edit:
I can help you in Python but i am sure there are many options here, like using a text editor's find and replace

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe your CSV file through `iconv`:

`echo "Ã©" | iconv -t latin1`

=> `é`

Comment: How I can do that with CSV file ? please